# How to run a line of code in debug mode only in Nim?

Tags: debugging, nim-lang

I have a line of code that I want to run in debug mode but not in release mode. Is there a way to automatically handle this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
when not defined(release):
  echo "Debug"
```

Compiler options set with `-d`, like `-d:release`, can be used in the program using the `defined` proc: https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#defined,untyped

Since it's available at compile-time we can use a `when` (compile-time if) instead of a regular runtime `if`.